# Button not doing what its programmed to do

Tags: android

I have 2 if statements where if the

```
modechoiceId == R.id.textmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal -- 1
```

OR

```
modechoiceId == R.id.animationmode && sizechoieId = R.id.normal -- 2
```

The (1) will make the nextButton go to a new Activity which is the textmode32by32.class and
the (2) will make the nextButton go to a new Activity which is the animationmode32by32.class.

Right now the problem is, both the options will go to the same page which is textmode32by32.class.

Does the problem lies in the RadioGroup? Or is the code in the if statement?

---

**startPage.class**

```
package tp.mp2014.dotmatrix;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class startPage extends Activity {

    Button backButton, nextButton;
    RadioGroup modeselection, sizeselection;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectionmode);

        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextselection);
        backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backselection);
        modeselection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.modeselection);
        sizeselection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.sizeselection);

        int modechoiceId = modeselection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int sizechoiceId = sizeselection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        if(modechoiceId == R.id.textmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal){

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextSelection = new Intent(startPage.this, textmode32by32.class);
                    startActivity(nextSelection);

                }
            });

        }

        else if(modechoiceId == R.id.animationmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal){

            nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent nextSelection1 = new Intent(startPage.this, animationmode32by32.class);
                    startActivity(nextSelection1);

                }
            });

        }

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent backSelection = new Intent(startPage.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(backSelection);

            }
        });




    }

}
```

**animationmode32by32.class**

```
package tp.mp2014.dotmatrix;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class animationmode32by32 extends Activity {

    Button nextBtn, backBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.animationmode32by32);

        backBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backBtn2);

        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent backSelection = new Intent(animationmode32by32.this, startPage.class);
                startActivity(backSelection);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**textmode32by32.class**

```
package tp.mp2014.dotmatrix;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class textmode32by32 extends Activity {

    Button nextBtn, backBtn;
    RadioButton left, stagnant, right;
    SeekBar scrollspeed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.textmode32by32);

    backBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backBtn1);

    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent backBtn = new Intent(textmode32by32.this, startPage.class);
            startActivity(backBtn);

        }
    });



    }



}
```

**selectionmode.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1H"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textmodeselection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textmodeselection"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textsizeselection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/textsizeselection"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/sizeselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/modeselection"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/modeselection" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/normal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/sizechoice1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/extended"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sizechoice2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/modeselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1H" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/textmode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/modechoice1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/animationmode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/modechoice2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/imagemode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/modechoice3" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextselection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your selectionmode.xml code

Comment: @madhu - Added it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int modechoiceId = modeselection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            int sizechoiceId = sizeselection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (modechoiceId == R.id.textmode
                    && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal) {

                //first
            } else if (modechoiceId == R.id.animationmode
                    && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal) {

                //second activity
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: worked. Mind explaining a bit? The main thing with my code and yours? I still don't get it though.

Comment: You can define multiple listeners for a button, but program always executes the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the `startPage` activity start it will set the button listener onclick directly to the `if(modechoiceId == R.id.textmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal)`

**Why???**

Because you are not changing it each time when another radio button is checked..

**solution:**

put the checking of radio button inside the onclick listener

**change this:**

```
if(modechoiceId == R.id.textmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal){

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nextSelection = new Intent(startPage.this, textmode32by32.class);
                startActivity(nextSelection);

            }
        });

    }

    else if(modechoiceId == R.id.animationmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal){

        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent nextSelection1 = new Intent(startPage.this, animationmode32by32.class);
                startActivity(nextSelection1);

            }
        });

    }
```

**to:**

```
 nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                int modechoiceId = modeselection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int sizechoiceId = sizeselection.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                if(modechoiceId == R.id.textmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal){

                   Intent nextSelection1 = new Intent(startPage.this, animationmode32by32.class);
                   startActivity(nextSelection1);

        }

                else if(modechoiceId == R.id.animationmode && sizechoiceId == R.id.normal){

                    Intent backSelection = new Intent(startPage.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(backSelection);
}
                }
            });
```